# Save matrix of double values in OpenCV

Tags: matrix, opencv, save, double

I have an OpenCV matrix of double (CV_32F) values. I'd like to save it to the disk. I know, I could convert it to an 1-Channel 8-bit IplImage and save it. But that way, I loose precision. Is there a way to save it directly in the 32-bit format, without having to convert it first? It also would be nice, if the resulting file would have an image format, so I can view the result as an image.

Comment: You want to view the result of a floating point image?

Comment: Yes indeed. I guess my question comes down to if there is a gray level image format with more than 8 bit per pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always save any "object" (CvMat, IplImage, anything..) from OpenCV "as is" by using cvSave() and loading it back with cvLoad(). As to my experience, most floating-point image stuff does not work correctly, I usually save my floating point data this way.
However, you cannot directly view the stored data.

Another possibility we have used frequently is including an own built of OpenEXR. You can easily store full precision floating point images using this library and many third party applications are able to open EXR files. Note that OpenCV includes OpenEXR, if i am not mistaken, but the last time i've tried, saving/loading floating point images did not work correctly. However, you should first try to save an fp image as *.exr, maybe that already does the magic with recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could always iterate over the matrix and write it out yourself. If you want it to be viewable as an image, you can use a variant of [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Gray_Map#PPM_example). I'm not sure what programs would be able to natively read your image format if you use values out of the 0-255 range though.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but thought I'd throw in my two cents.

If you just want to save float images to disk, and you don't need to view them, you may want to look at Portable Float Map (PFM) image format. Very simple format, just saves floats to disk, no compression, minimal header. You can write your own read/write code for this very quickly. That's what I'm using for HDR research.

As the others pointed out, to "view" float images you need to ask yourself some questions about their contents and how to sensibly scale them back into an 8-bit range you can display on your monitor. You might consider Matlab's image viewer (imshow function) which offers some double scaling functionality.

You might also consider saving to either EXR or HDR format and using Photomatix's built-in HDR image viewer which gives you a little separate window that shows you a real-time tonemapped window around your current cursor position. It's a good way to navigate an HDR or floating point image to get a sense of "what's really there" without tonemapping the whole thing.